# Linkedin Group API

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

This is regarding about LinkedIn group API. I'm using this API to get relevant data from a specific group. My area of concern is where to find Linkedin API and how to use it. I have search a lot but landed no where. If anyone can provide some examples regarding group API that would be really helpful.

I use `JavaScript` with this API feather more i use [apigee console](https://apigee.com/console/linkedin) as well

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/4058745/posts:(creation-timestamp,title,summary,creator:(first-name,last-name,picture-url,headline),likes,attachment:(image-url,content-domain,content-url,title,summary),relation-to-viewer)
```

Above execution landed successfully when it comes to real implementation i got stuck

- Requirement is to retrieve group discussions from a specific group using `JavaScript API`

  Is there any advantages to go with `JavaScript` rather than REST?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSAPI is a complementary API to the REST API - it allows developers to integrate the LinkedIn API into web pages without having to expose their secret (or their users' secrets). There are convenience methods for many of the calls which make it easier to make the calls you want.  However, you're not limited to the implemented convenience methods - you can wrap any REST API call in a Raw JSAPI call.So the main advantage of the JSAPI is that it can be used from within a web page.  If you're already running a server and have methods to store tokens for your users, you would probably be better off using the REST API directly.Hope this helps.

Comment: Is the Linkedin Groups API now closed? I tried the above query after allowing Apigee to use my Linkedin account (so it shows linkedin-AuthenticatedUser): it returns 403 Access to groups denied. Only these API categories are shown: Login, Share, Companies.